# Python 3.4 PySide Install Issues

Tags: python, installation, pyside

I'm trying to install PySide for use with Python 3.4 but I am having some issues. I've tried to install using pip with python3-pyside as well as dnf install python3-pyside.

Neither of these find any such package and I am unable to find any repo with the package, is there another way to install it?

Answer (score 1):

Get your version here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyside

and then install with pip as usual.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I downloaded the one for my python install (PySide‑1.2.2‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl for Python 3.4). I tried to pip3 install but it said it was not a supported wheel. Is there some other setup required?

Comment: I didn't read that web page correctly, that was supplying windows wheels but my system is Linux